# ASP.NET MVC4 Code First and Unit Testing Tutorials/Advice

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

**I'm not typically looking for an answer to every question here but more links to learning resources and perhaps advice about some of my points**

I'm trying to implement Unit Testing in a project of mine but I can't find any tutorials (ideally video tutorials) that go into *enough* detail.

A- 1. How do I separate the concerns *enough* to unit test my functionality individually?

A- 2. What should I focus most on testing and where I should draw the line?

A- 3. What should an individual Unit Test cover and at what point should I break it down into 2 unit tests?

So I'm using Code First I've built up a product model, controller and views:

```
    //
    // GET: /Product/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(product);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Product/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(product);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestEditView() {
        // Arrange
        ProductController controller = new ProductController();

        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Edit(2) as ViewResult;

        // Assert
        //make sure theres a result
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        //make sure it's the right results
        Assert.AreEqual("Edit", result.ViewName);
        //test a dropdownlist exists
        Assert.IsNotNull(result.ViewBag.CategoryID);
    }
```

B- 1. How should I test my POST method? Should I add in an extra layer for data management so I can write up unit tests to test that individually?

B- 2. Should I focus more on checking the view is returned or more on the data 
 (for example: if I have a Edit.cshtml then it will always return (why test that?), the data returned is more important isn't it? or are my black boxes more important? or should I cover all 3?)

B- 3. Should I break down my Unit Test to test the view and data separately?

Again, there's a lot of questions but I think mainly I'm looking for examples, tutorials and ways to learn about how to use Unit Testing (and even MVC) as best as I can.

Answer (score 2):

I found the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 4 to be a great resource.  It does a good job of covering unit testing in the context of an MVC project using EF.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "Unity ,dependency injection with unit testing"

More details, please visit these below links

[Link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh323690%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Link2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33091/Using-a-Unity-Container-with-Dependency-Injection)